# Property 'active' does not exist on type 'component' angular error

Tags: angular, typescript, typeerror

Property 'active' does not exist on type 'component' angular error while compiling and building application

Comment: can you include some code to showcase what is there ?

Comment: Property 'active' does not exist on type 'TabStripTabComponent'.

Comment: can you include the definition of the class `TabStripTabComponent` in your question ?

Comment: Do you see any property named `active` in that class ?

Comment: Check if you have missed something or mistyped, like having `ngFor="active of someting"` instead of `ngFor="let active of something"` etc. Check where `active` is being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any code to help you better. I'm just guessing here. Though, maybe you are using something like this:

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success clearfix bottom-buffer" [routerLink]="[recipe.id]" [routerLinkActive]="active">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe.name}}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{recipe.description}}</p>
  </div>

  <span class="pull-right">
    <img
      [src]="recipe.imagePath"
      alt="{{recipe.name}}"
      class="img-responsive img-rounded"
      style="max-height: 50px"
    >
  </span>
</a>
```

But instead you should be using this:

```
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success clearfix bottom-buffer" [routerLink]="[recipe.id]" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe.name}}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{recipe.description}}</p>
  </div>

  <span class="pull-right">
    <img
      [src]="recipe.imagePath"
      alt="{{recipe.name}}"
      class="img-responsive img-rounded"
      style="max-height: 50px"
    >
  </span>
</a>
```

It just happened to me a few moments ago.

**In Summary:**

You must pass the css class 'active' into the routerLinkActive directive with a squared bracket syntax, using single quotes inside of the double quotes. Or between double brackets without the squared bracket syntax.

So, you can do this:

```
routerLinkActive="active"
```

...or this:

```
[routerLinkActive]="'active'"
```

But you can't do this:

```
[routerLinkActive]="active"
```